# Javascript not recognizing controller

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am having issues with code that have worked before but now is not working. The issue is i am calling a Controller called GetRooms from my cshtml class but i am getting a 404 error.

Controller:

```
public virtual ActionResult GetRooms(Guid unitId, Guid interviewId, DateTime date, DateTime startTime, DateTime endTime)
{

}
```

In my cshtml class i have implemented a getJSON requst with the paramesters:

```
function getRoomsInUnit(unitId, interviewId, date, startTime, endTime) {
$.getJSON('/CitizenMentor/GetRooms', { unitId: unitId, interviewId: interviewId, date: date, startTime: startTime, endTime: endTime }, function (result) {
    var list = $('#SelectedRoomResourceId');
    list.find('option').remove();

    $(result).each(function (index, room) {
        list.append('<option value="' + room.Id + '">' + room.Title + '</option>');
    });
});
```

};

When i run the code i am getting a 404 error stating that a controller with the parameters cannot be found. I cant seem to find out why this is happening. Maybe its the timestamp that is sent with my query??
[image]

Comment: And your controller is `CitizenMentorController`?

Comment: yes it is. I am calling an Add and Edit method witch is working fine. but not the GetRooms method

Comment: I note your referrer is `/ka/Mentor/Overview`. Is it correct to leave out `/ka` in your path? Can you browse to the path manually? Have you tried the [Route debugger](https://www.nuget.org/packages/routedebugger/)?

Comment: What happens if you try to reach directly the url? Do you have a routeConfig defining the url type you're trying to reach?

Comment: the issue was actually that the url has been changed. thanks for the help guys .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change the link like this and use ajax.

```
var roomDetails =
{ unitId: unitId, 
  interviewId: interviewId,
  date: date, 
  startTime: startTime, 
  endTime: endTime 
}
   $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("GetRooms", "CitizenMentor")',
            type: 'GET',
            data: roomDetails ,
            success: function (data) {
                var list = $('#SelectedRoomResourceId');
                 list.find('option').remove();
          $(result).each(function (index, room) {
          list.append('<option value="' + room.Id + '">' + room.Title +'</option>');
                }

            },
            error: function () {
                alert("something seems wrong", "Error");
            }
```